# What parameters should be considered while finding rare words in Wikipedia?

Tags: nlp

I am trying to find rare words in wikipedia and analyse them. But, I encounter this issue, rare words what we mean by classical English type sophisticated words are not present in wikipedia at large. Maybe 1/2 max in an article but in context of explaining something deep. Otherwise rare words just means moderate common English words which if you are a native speaker and studied English attentively, you'll find them fairly common.

Which made me ask this question, when we refer to rare words in Wikipedia, what should be the parameters we consider. We can obviously rely on Word frequency or sophisticated techniques such as measuring word rarity or painstankingly train a neural net model after preparing a dataset.

I want all your opinions, what you consider as rare words in wikipedia and how fairly common you think those rare words are? Will be glad to read everyone's opinions